# Area of $\left( \frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{25} \right)^2 \le x^2 + y^2$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I've used the modified polar coordinates: $x = 3r \cos \theta$, $y =5r \sin \theta$, which got me to

$$r^2 \le 9 \cos^2 \theta + 25 \sin^2 \theta$$

What now?

Comment: @shimme, where are equations of the curves?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I don't understand. Which curves?

Comment: @shimme, then whose areas are to be calculated?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee in the title (that is: the area enclosed by the inequality)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on a right path. The following limits are ones you are looking for:

$$r|_0^{\sqrt{9+16\sin^2(\theta)}},\theta|_0^{2\pi}$$

[image]

Comment: wait a minute, what's become of the cosine?

Comment: @shimee: $9\cos^2(t)+25\sin^2(t)=9(\cos^2(t)+\sin^2(t))+16\sin^2(t)$

Comment: so the answer should be $$\int_0^{2 \pi} \int_0^{\sqrt{9+16\sin^2 \theta}} r dr d\theta = 17 \pi$$

Comment: It is late, I am feelinng dense. Since we are not quite using polar coordinates, is the Jacobian really $r\,dr\,d\theta$?

Comment: @AndréNicolas, yes it is since $\frac{1}{2}\int_{\alpha}^{\beta}r^2 d \theta $

Comment: nice picture +1

Comment: Nice work, Babak!